# Within a helper method,the '*' of 1*mock.method() is recognized as multiplication sign

Tags: spock

I tried to move some verifications from

```
then:
   1*mock.method()
   result.value>0
```

to helper method like this,

```
 def reusedVerification(Mock mock,Model result){
     assert 1*mock.method()
     assert result.Value>0
 }
```

but spock givens me an error like this

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method
java.lang.Integer#multiply.Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null]
due to overlapping prototypes between:
     [class java.lang.Character]
     [class java.lang.Number]
at .....
```

I think that the '*' sign was recognized as multiplication sign in helper method,how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix verifications and assertions in the same helper method.

You can have 2 helper methods. One to do the verifications and one to do the assertions. For example:

```
  then:
   interaction { reusedVerifications(theMock) }
   reusedAssertions(theResult)
```

The helper verification method must be called from inside an [explicit interaction block](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_explicit_interaction_blocks) and might look like:

```
 def reusedVerifications(Mock mock){
     1 * mock.method()
     1 * mock.someOtherMethod()
 }
```

The assertion helper method must have asserts in it. For example:

```
 def reusedAssertions(Model result){
     assert result.Value > 0
     assert result.Message == "Failure"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spock's mock verification syntax only works directly in the body of the test.